# C# How to change the Variable Value in the BaseClass if the new Variable into the derived Class are changed

Tags: c#

I have a bigger Projekt and I would like to change a variable value into the BaseClass if the variable value into the derived class are changed.
Here a simple Example.

What I want are, if I change the value Obj.ModelTyp.Name to “Name123“ then the Base.ModelTyp.Name gets the same value “Name123“ automatically.
Is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks Steffen

```
namespace Question
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataObjekt Obj = new DataObjekt();
```

`Obj.ModelTyp.Name = "Name123";  // is there a Way to Change Base.ModelTyp.Name  
                                            // if Obj.ModelTyp.Name is changed?
            Obj.ModelTyp.Data = "4567";

            Obj.DoSomithing();
    }
}

public class FirstBaseClass
{
    public FirstBaseClass() { ModelTyp = new BaseType(); }
    public BaseType ModelTyp { get; set; }
}

public class SecondBaseClass : FirstBaseClass
{
    public void DoSomithing()
    {
        string Test = this.ModelTyp.Name;  // there is nothing because Base.ModelTyp.Name 
                                          //but I Want to have "Name123"
    }
}

public class DataObjekt : SecondBaseClass
{
    public DataObjekt() { ModelTyp = new ObjektData(); }
    new public ObjektData ModelTyp { get; set; }
}

public class BaseType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ObjektData : BaseType
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}`

}

Comment: You really want two properties named ModelTyp (one of type BaseData and one of type ObjektData) in your class DataObjekt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes' relationships seem really complicated and convoluted. You should probably consider simplifying it a bit.

Anyway, the reason why your code does not work now is because you hid the base class' `ModelTyp` property, and created another new `ModelTyp` property in `DataObjekt`. Hopefully you already knew this.

But you don't *really* want to create a brand new, separate property, do you? You just want to change the type of `ModelTyp` to `ObjektData`. Therefore, you can just make `DataObjekt.ModelTyp` refer to the same thing as `FirstBaseClass.ModelTyp` in the constructor:

```
public DataObjekt() { 
    ModelTyp = new ObjektData();
    base.ModelTyp = this.ModelTyp; // <- this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks :), this is the line I'am looking for :)